# Xpath conditioning in datamapper using rule

Tags: xpath, mule, datamapper, rule

If the below XML is evaluated using datamapper to map only even numbered id's to output then the condition using xpath(Rule) is : ?

```
 <employees>
        <employee>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>aaa</name>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>bbb</name>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>ccc</name>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <id>4</id>
            <name>ddd</name>
        </employee>
    </employees>
```

I tried using **/employee[id mod 2 = 0]/id**. It maps if the input has only one even number and fails if it has more than one even numbered id in the input.xml.
    The error is

> Result of xpath filling field 'id' contains two or more values!

Comment: On that error, obviously that xpath is expected to return a list.. Anyway, I don't understand how you use datamapper and that xpath. If you wished to map only entries with even ID. Maybe transform your input first to include only those entries via XSLT before datamapper.

Comment: Not sure, but you can try this.1. Make sure when you are writing the rules in DM, its dataType is ( List instead of string) if the values of the field is list. If this is not a list, then it result in one value as you mentioned. 2.  Make sure you are in Proper For each of DataMapper  for its routing. Sometime for each will point its parent hierarchy then the root tag of child, may result in improper looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules are independent to each Element Mapping configured in DM. Rules are to be created in the element mapping configuration it is intended to be used in.

For the sample xml provided, this rule should be created in `Foreach 'employee' -> 'employee'` element mapping.

Try this for the rule configuration

    `Name : {Rule Name}
    Type : Boolean
    Context : /employees/employee
    Xpath : /matches(string(id mod 2), '0')`

This creates a rule returning true if id is even and false if id is odd.

Use an if block in DM script view and check for the rule's value. if rule value is true, only then map the id.

Comment: It also worked in this way                                                                          
    Name : {Rule Name}
    Type : String
    Context : /employees/employee
    Xpath : /id mod 2 = 0 
and used the if condition as below : 
if(input.Ruleid.equals("true")){
 output.id = input.id;
 output.name = input.name;
} and is there any other way to do this without using if condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
It also worked in this way                                                                          
    Name : {Rule Name}
    Type : String
    Context : /employees/employee
    Xpath : /id mod 2 = 0 
and used the if condition as below : 
if(input.Ruleid.equals("true")){
    output.id = input.id;
    output.name = input.name;
}
```

Is there any other way to do this without using if condition.